# Using date_part function in Order by clause always returns columns must appear in the Group by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to arrange the hour values of particular date column as my own so i have used below query,

```
SELECT SUM("sa_bikedata"."_Duration") AS "Chart_Column_1",       
date_part('hour',"sa_bikedata"."_Start_date") AS "Chart_Column_0"     
FROM "sa"."bikedata" AS "sa_bikedata"     
GROUP BY date_part('hour',"sa_bikedata"."_Start_date")    
ORDER BY CASE CAST(date_part('hour',"sa_bikedata"."_Start_date") as VARCHAR)    
WHEN '1' THEN'0' WHEN '2' THEN'1' WHEN '3' THEN'2' 
WHEN '4' THEN'3' WHEN '5' THEN'4' WHEN '6' THEN'5'
WHEN '7' THEN'6' WHEN '8' THEN'7' WHEN '9' THEN'8'
WHEN '10' THEN'09' WHEN '0' THEN'10'          
ELSE date_part('hour',"sa_bikedata"."_Start_date")  END  LIMIT 1000  OFFSET 0;
```

But it always returns the error,

> ERROR:  column "sa_bikedata._Start_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 4: ORDER BY CASE date_part('hour',"sa_bikedata"."_Start_date")

I want to get the result in data table as

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
0
```

Comment: Please take a few moments and fix your formatting.  Add _four_ or more spaces to each line which contains code, to render it as monospaced text.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error with your query. Could you create a fiddle (like on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk), ...) with which the error is reproduced?

Comment: Hi Trincot, I have installed postgres version 10 in my machine. In the Postgres server itself, the above query returns error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is due to improper usage of *CASE* syntax near *ORDER BY*. Below is the syntax of order by with case,

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN(condition) THEN result
```

So the query should be like below,

```
    SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN ("trxtype"<> 'POH') THEN ( "trxamt") ELSE ( 0) END ) AS 
    "Chart_Column_3",CAST(date_part('hour',"trxdate") AS VARCHAR) AS "Chart_Column_7"  
    FROM "POS.Sales".postrx POS GROUP BY  CAST(date_part('hour',"trxdate") AS VARCHAR) 
    ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN(CAST(date_part('hour',"trxdate") AS VARCHAR) = '7') THEN'0'
    WHEN(CAST(date_part('hour',"trxdate") AS VARCHAR) = '8') THEN '1'
    ...
    END  LIMIT 1000  OFFSET 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error says exactly what is wrong. You cannot use `_Start_date` in the `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` without an aggregate function in the `SELECT`. You have to tell Postgres how to aggregate within the groups, so maybe use `AVG(date_part('hour',"sa_bikedata"."_Start_date")) AS "Chart_Column_0"` instead!?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM("sa_bikedata"."_Duration") AS "Chart_Column_1",       
       date_part('hour', "sa_bikedata"."_Start_date") AS "Chart_Column_0"     
FROM "sa"."bikedata" AS "sa_bikedata"     
GROUP BY "Chart_Column_0"
ORDER BY ( "Chart_Column_0" = '0' ) DESC,  -- put `0` last
         "Chart_Column_0"
LIMIT 1000  OFFSET 0;
```